# Method to construct instances from strings and return them with their type?

Tags: java

Given two classes `A` and `B` with one-argument constructors and a binary function `f`, I need to parse strings of the form

```
"f(A(10), B(20))"
"f(A(2), A(3))"
```

create the appropriate instances and call the respective functions:

```
class Functions {
    public static double f(A a1, A a2);
    public static double f(A a, B b);
    public static double f(B b1, B b2);
    // ...
}
```

So what I am looking for is a method of the kind

```
T createInstanceFromString(String desc);
```

to create the instances from strings like "A(10)" or "B(20)". Of course and unfortunately, this is impossible in Java.

Any advice on solutions to this problem are greatly appreciated.

*Edit*: I forgot to mention that there is a potentially large number of different classes `A`, `B`, `C`, etc and a large number of functions `f`, `g`, etc. I'd like to use `createInstanceFromString` to separate the parsing from calling, otherwise one has to conditionally parse separately for each function call, which would bring a lot of code duplication.

*Edit2*: The question is not about how to parse, but about how to parse and then return an instance in a general purpose method/factory/whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tokenize the String.
(if it always starts with `f(` and ends with `)` you can make your life easier, be removing these parts).

A(4) -> Find the Classname -> A -> find the Parameter -> 4

This is done like this (pseudo java code):

```
public static Object createClass(String className, Double value){
    Class a = Class.forName(className);
    Class[] params = new Class[]{Integer.class};
    Constructor c = a.getConstructor(params);
    Object[] values = new Object[]{value};
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

Maybe, this lik is helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

**update**
This is like writing a compiler. You can get further information, if you read something about, how to write a compiler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

**update 2**
put all generated instances into an array. Now you can get the correct method f with the reflections-API. The Code will be something like

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class...)

```
Object[] values ...
Class[] classes ...
for(Object o: values){
    add o.getClass() to classes
}

Method f = Functions.getClass().getDeclaredMethods("f", classes);
f.invoke(values);
```

Comment: This is most likely the approach the OP needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't see how this will do what I need. In the last line, you explicitly cast to `A`, so you'll have a switch statement to also handle the case of parsing `B`. Now if I wrap your code in a method, what type do I return? It could be `A` or `B`...

Comment: Return Object, the JVM will call the correct method for you. The Code was only one part of the solution. Calling newInstance(), will create an instance of A (the cast is not needed, for the JVM)

Comment: I'll try this. I'm coming from C++ and didn't know that the JVM is doing some magic to do the `Object` to either `A` or `B` cast ...

Comment: The magic is done with Class.forName("A"). From that time, any instance is from type A. Thats why it will be passed to f(A) and not into f(B).

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately I think I still don't get it. `createClass` returns an `Object`, so `f(createClass("A",1), createClass("B",2))` doesn't compile: "the method f(A, A) is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object)". Intuitively this makes sense, doesn't it? Casting works, but this brings me back to square one.

Comment: My fault. If you know all Classes, you can write a createA(value) and a createB(value), which returns the correct return-types.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me enough pointers to make it work! I'll update my question with a working example solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a class for each function and call a static method like "compute".
This way you parse the class name and attributes from the String and load the appropiate class via an class loader. You can pass a variable amount of parameters via an array or variables with a HashMap which contains the name as key and the variable as value.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but looks like you can get the class by

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("NameOfTheWantedClass");
```

and than

```
Constructor[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
```

and than search for the wanted constructor by using

```
getParameterTypes()
```

on each constructor and select the wanted one.

But I recommend to think about changing your approach, Usage of `Class.forName("NameOfTheWantedClass")` or `reflection`has always a smell of bad practice. And should only be used when really necessary.